# Javascript: How to call a method on a dynamically determined variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of objects assigned to variables:

```
var ElectricCar = {
    start: function(){ alert('started electric car') }
};

var BioDieselCar = {
    start: function(){ alert('started bio diesel car') }
};
```

I want to call the start method on one of these objects, but I only have a string to work with:

```
var Starter = {
    init: function(carType){
        //... start the car that matches car type
    }
};

Starter.init('ElectricCar');
```

How can I call the start method on the appropriate object?

Comment: depends on where your code resides. Why you use var statement? Is is it inside a function?

Comment: just a way to create objects with methods I can call.

Comment: Do you know, that var is for making the scope of a variable local?

Comment: yes, but I don't think it matters since they are defined at the top level and not inside anything.

Comment: that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred technique would require refactoring your code slightly.

```
var cars = {
    ElectricCar: {
        start: function(){ alert('started electric car') }
    },
    BioDieselCar: {
        start: function(){ alert('started bio diesel car') }
    }
};

var carType = 'ElectricCar';

// access the properties of cars by string
cars[carType].start();
```

This technique is preferable because it avoids the use of `eval`.  By converting your vars to properties of an object, you can reference them by string.

Comment: @Andrew - Wouldn't that be practically the same thing?  Just move the `cars[carType].Start();` into `init`.  Now it looks even more like a factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
this[carType]( );
```

Comment: Nice! just needs to be `this[carType].start()`

Comment: i updated my code sample a little bit. I realized variable scope may be an important consideration.

Answer (score 1):

```
self[carType].start()
```

self is like window if you have no frames, but differs if you have